# Не отображаются изображения в ImageView

Tags: android

В среде разработки, во вкладке `Design` в `AndroidStudio` показывает изображение, но при запуске почему то нет, не могу понять почему. Изображение с расширением `.png` Название `icon_like`, `icon_view`, `icon_dis_like`. Они хранятся в папке `res/drawble`.

Код разметки:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".playerVideo.PlayerActivity">

    ...  

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/statisticImageWidth"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/statisticImageHeight"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_like"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/statisticImageWidth"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/statisticImageHeight"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_view"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/statisticImageWidth"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/statisticImageHeight"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_dis_like"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Дизайн]
[image: Как он выглядит в телефоне]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tools:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_like"` - пространство имён `tools` (`http://schemas.android.com/tools`) как раз таки и обозначает, что параметр указан только для среды разработки и не будет включён в сборку.
Стандартные параметры задаются с `android:`.
Атрибут `srcCompat` принадлежит библиотеке поддержки. Для его использования нужно добавить пространство имён `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".playerVideo.PlayerActivity">

    ...  

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/statisticImageWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/statisticImageHeight"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_like"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/statisticImageWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/statisticImageHeight"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_view"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/statisticImageWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/statisticImageHeight"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_dis_like"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Я как-то не в курсе для чего нынче используют библиотечный `srcCompat`, но простую картинку можно задать стандартным `android:src`